# Spring Boot connect to remote ip

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, application.properties

I need to connect to remote ip database, the ip has itself a port number associated with it. My database port is 1433.

I am using the following connection string in my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:XXXX:1433;databaseName=test
```

I am getting connection error due to invalid port. How to do that?

Comment: why use ;database

Comment: sry. i thought mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

> x.x.x.x:XXXX:1433.

This doesn't make any sense. IP cannot have a port associated with it. IP will get you till the machine; and port number will take you to the app which listens to that port.

It has to be either XXXX or 1433. Not both!

### Edit

What you should do is, talk to your network admin folks to configure port forwarding on your NAT - this means that the NAT will listen on a port you specify, and all communication which reaches this port will be forwarded to the MS SQL Servers internal IP + another port you specify, for example: 148.25.6.22:1433 => 172.16.0.61:1433. Now, if your appserver connects to 148.25.6.22:1433, the packets will reach the MS SQL Server at port 1433.

A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619341/6785908

Comment: I am using the remote machine of my workstation. so ip is the public ip of the workstation and port is for each machine.

Comment: You have to talk to the network admin whoever owns that NAT and ask them to map a port for you!. Edited my answer